# ColorBox malfunctioning in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using ColorBox straight out the box to display nine images. It works very well in Chrome but not so in Firefox and IE.

In both these browsers, when each successive image loads, it displays about 70px lower that the previous, so that by the time I get to the last image it is no longer visible on the first screen of the page. I have to scroll down to find it.

I've uploaded my page at http://www.lakesidesurrey.co.uk/group/biog/index.html.

I am using HTML 4.01 transitional DTD.

Would appreciate any assistance to rectify this.

Thanks
Terry

Comment: its working fine on both FF11 and IE9 for me

Answer (score 0):

you might want to replace your current jquery.colorbox.js with a new one.  I just committed a bug fix that probably resolves your issue.